# How to display Username after login using anchor tag

Tags: php

I want to display the current users name by using anchor tag but it doesnt show the users name. I have already included the DB connection and sesstion_start at the very top of my code. I have tried other methods but doesnt seem to work. I having trouble to make the code run right. I hope someone can help me. Thank you

```
   <li>
            <a href="<?php
                   if(isset($_SESSION['FirstName'])){
                       echo 'Welcome'.', '.$_SESSION['FirstName']." ".$_SESSION['LastName'];
                                }
                        ?>"></a>
                        <ul>
                            <li style="padding-left: 6px; padding-bottom: 10px;"><a href="#">History</a></li>
                            <li style="padding-left: 1px; padding-bottom: 10px;"><a href="#">Teachers</a></li>
                            <li style="padding-left: 10px; padding-bottom: 10px;"><a href="#">About</a></li>
                            <li style="padding-left: 6px; padding-bottom: 10px;"><a href="logout.php?logout-submit=logout" name="logout"> Logout </a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
```

LOGIN CODE:

```
<?php
    include "includes/config.php";
    
  session_start();
if(isset($_POST['loginbutton'])){

$username = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['user']);
$password = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['password']);





    $sql_query = "SELECT * FROM tbl_useraccounts WHERE employee_id = '$username'";
    $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql_query);



 $row=mysqli_fetch_array($result);

            $passwordhashed = password_verify($password, $row['password']);
    if($passwordhashed){
            $_SESSION['username'] = $row['employee_id'];
            $_SESSION['usertype'] = $row['usertype'];
            if($_SESSION['usertype'] == 'Admin'){
             echo "<script>alert('Successfully logged in!');</script>";
             header('location: HomeForAdmin.php');
             die();
            }
            if($_SESSION['usertype'] == 'SuperAdmin'){
                echo "<script>alert('Successfully logged in!');</script>";
                header('location: HomeForSuperAdmin.php');
                die();
            }
            else{
                echo "<script>alert('Incorrect username and password!');document.location='login2.php'</script>";
            }
    }
    
    else{
        echo "<script>alert('Incorrect credentials!');document.location='login2.php'</script>";
    }

            $_SESSION['username'] = $row['employee_id'];
            $_SESSION['password'] = $row['password'];
            $_SESSION['usertype'] = $row['usertype'];
            $_SESSION['first_name'] = $row['FirstName'];
            $_SESSION['last_name'] = $row['LastName'];
            



}



?>`
```

Comment: [Anchor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a) element is for hyperlinks. You can set `href` param to an URL and put any text inside like this: `<a href="https://stackoverflow.com">Stack Overflow</a>`.

Comment: I only did this kinds of code because when I dont remove the anchor tag the design will be gone. @Vitalii

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have tried right.
Instead of writing inside the `href=""`. Write down inside the anchor tag.

for eg :

```
<a>Users Name</a>
```

Code

```
<a href=""><?php
  if(isset($_SESSION['first_name'])){
    echo 'Welcome'.', '.$_SESSION['first_name']." ".$_SESSION['last_name'];
  }
?></a>
```

**Issue In Login Page**

In your home page you are checking the session 'FirstName' Which you have never set it.

```
isset($_SESSION['FirstName'])
```

And you are trying to print that session value.

```
echo 'Welcome'.', '.$_SESSION['FirstName']." ".$_SESSION['LastName'];
```

In your login page you use that key to set the session for first and last name `first_name` and `last_name`.

Instead of accessing the session using same key you are using `FirstName` and `LastName`, Which doesn't exist.

Try this code for Login Page.

```
<?php
    include "includes/config.php";
    
    session_start();
    if(isset($_POST['loginbutton']))
    {
        $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['user']);
        $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['password']);

        $sql_query = "SELECT * FROM tbl_useraccounts WHERE employee_id = '$username'";
        $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql_query);

        $row=mysqli_fetch_array($result);

        $passwordhashed = password_verify($password, $row['password']);
        if($passwordhashed)
        {
            $_SESSION['username'] = $row['employee_id'];
            $_SESSION['usertype'] = $row['usertype'];
            $_SESSION['password'] = $row['password'];
            $_SESSION['usertype'] = $row['usertype'];
            $_SESSION['first_name'] = $row['FirstName'];
            $_SESSION['last_name'] = $row['LastName'];
            if($_SESSION['usertype'] == 'Admin'){
             echo "<script>alert('Successfully logged in!');</script>";
             header('location: HomeForAdmin.php');
             die();
            }
            if($_SESSION['usertype'] == 'SuperAdmin'){
                echo "<script>alert('Successfully logged in!');</script>";
                header('location: HomeForSuperAdmin.php');
                die();
            }
            else{
                echo "<script>alert('Incorrect username and password!');document.location='login2.php'</script>";
            }
        }
        else{
            echo "<script>alert('Incorrect credentials!');document.location='login2.php'</script>";
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Unfortunately still doesnt work. it still doesnt show the Users name :<

Comment: What are your getting, please mention it in your question.

Comment: To Debug the error, please use the else condition to check that the session is set or not.

Comment: I want to display the users name after they login for example "Welcome, User123" that user123 must come from the database. I hope that clears that up.

Comment: Yeah @RappaAshura , can you please add your login code into your question.

Comment: I have updated my answer, please check it.

Comment: Copied the all the code you have given but unfortunately it still doesnt work. :<

Comment: Answer Updated. @RappaAshura, Try it again, I hope now it will work.

Comment: it finally worked! sorry if you had to change all my code. Thank you!